# Using Parse Despite Shut Down

Tags: parse-platform

As most developers know at this point, Parse is shutting down early 2017 but they have been pushing clients to migrate their services. I have a huge client who will be using Parse for Push Notifications in July and August and want to make sure that Parse will still be functioning 100%. I understand them wanting people to migrate, but they don't seem clear on whether their services will be interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

They have been very clear about it :

[image]

Why are you using Parse when they are going to shut down & want you to adopt mongoDb? If you have an app there with mongo your app would work fine, but why not go with other options?

Refer : [Parse Migration](http://www.parse.com/migration)
Also read : [My app relies on parse, I have no backend skills](https://www.quora.com/Parse-just-shut-down-My-app-completely-relies-on-Parse-and-I-have-no-backend-skills-What-can-I-do)

Comment: Ani, I understand these recommended dates, but we did not change anything for the April 28 deadline and everything works just fine. Does this mean if we wait until after July 28 nothing will happen as well?

Answer (score 0):

Parse.com will be fully functional until the shutdown on January 28, 2017 although with weaker performance after April 28th.

According to members of the Parse team:

> Hi there, I'm part of the team who is actively helping people migrate
>   their apps. The answer is that we don't know how this may affect push
>   notifications.
>
> When we announced that the hosted Parse service will be shut down next
>   January, we also provided a migration guide where we have shared a
>   recommended set of guidelines for your migration:
>
> Migrate your database by April 28th, 2016 Migrate your API traffic by
>   July 28th, 2016 We are committed to maintaining the Parse API up and
>   running until January of next year, but we highly recommend starting
>   your migration work as soon as possible. We are focusing our efforts
>   on people who are following our recommended instructions.
>   [Source](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/921)

and

> If you have migrated your database to your own MongoDB, you will be
>   fine, your apps will receive full priority. If you haven't migrated
>   your database, you app will keep working, but requests might take
>   longer or have a higher failure rate.
>   [Source](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1145)